# Titanium - Facebook login doesn't show on device

Tags: android, facebook, module, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm trying to create a login with Facebook using the Facebook modules that comes in Titanium framework.

When I do a button click on the iphone emulator I get the login screen to Facebook. But when I install on the device I don't get the login screen - as if doesn't do anything (no errors). I've placed an alert to see that that place of code is called when the button clicks - it does.

here's my code on button click:

```
Alloy.Globals.Facebook.permissions = ['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email', 'user_about_me', 'user_events', 'user_hometown',
        'user_likes', 'user_photos', 'user_posts', 'user_videos', 'user_tagged_places', 'user_work_history'];
Alloy.Globals.Facebook.addEventListener('login', function(e) {
    // do some stuff
}
Alloy.Globals.Facebook.initialize();
Alloy.Globals.Facebook.authorize();
```

Again - on emulator works well, on device not showing facebook login.

Comment: You say "emulator", so I assume you're targeting Android? What Titanium and FB module version? Did you try without all the permissions?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? We're having the same issue. (It will for some devices, some times)

Comment: @user984003 I've answered my own question below. This what helped me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS you need to have the following in `tiapp.xml`:

```
            <!-- Enable App Transport Security for Facebook -->
            <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>facebook.com</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                        <true/>
                        <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                        <false/>
                    </dict>
                    <key>fbcdn.net</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                        <true/>
                        <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                        <false/>
                    </dict>
                    <key>akamaihd.net</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                        <true/>
                        <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                        <false/>
                    </dict>
                </dict>
```

And on Android:

```
        <application>
            <activity android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
            <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        </application>
```