# Titanium - Couldn't find module localStrings

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Out of the bloom, when I try to run my app (device and simulator) I get the red screen saying:

```
Couldn't find module: localStrings for architecture: x86_64
```

I tried cleaning the project. Restarting the machine... still the same.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Found out this happens when I'm using LiveView. If I run without LiveView the app loads. But until now I've always run with LiveView since it makes dev faster.

**Edit II**

I've tried updating to latest node version - doesn't help. I've debugged `liveview.js` plugin in the Studio directory - the url is `127.0.0.1` - I think it's fine, all-tough where does `localhost` refers to in emulator - to mac host or the emulator device itself?

Comment: If you are on Mac, check if you have a `.DS_Store` file (it's a hidden file) in i18n folder or in i18n/en. If yes, delete it.

Comment: @ThomasLemaitre Yes, on Mac. And no - don't have .DS_Store in that directory.

Comment: But do you see hidden file on Finder ? (if not, check this link : http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/quickly-showhide-hidden-files-mac-os-x-mavericks/). If you haven't a .DS_Store file, try to remove the i18n/ folder and rebuild. If it works, maybe there is a wrong character in your file, or an unclosed tag

Comment: @ThomasLemaitre No. There isn't any hidden files in that directory. I've removed the content of the file from all my values - didn't help.

Comment: Ok, it's seems to be a NodeJS version error, which one do you have ? Try to update NodeJS : https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-7747

Comment: @ThomasLemaitre my nodejs version is 5.4.1 (hadn't changed since it did work). I've tried the workaround suggested in Q&A - didn't help.

Comment: @ThomasLemaitre see me answer (down) to my own question - might be a new appc bug.

Answer (score 0):

**Found the problem - a new bug**

I recently asked a question about Facebook login not working on my phone ([Titanium - Facebook login doesn't show on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36071120/titanium-facebook-login-doesnt-show-on-device)). I found that I have miss-configured `NSAppTransportSecurity` in `tiapp.xml` and fixed it.

After doing some debugging the the current issue I have found the following:

> Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

After quick search I have remembered that I have fixed my Facebook login option. After removing that code from `tiapp.xml` app is back working with `LiveView`.

You can find more information about `NSAppTransportSecurity` here: [Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

The current workaround that works for me is adding this to `NSAppTransportSecurity` section of `tiapp.xml`

**NOTE:** this workaround is NOT safe and you would probably want to remove it from production apps):

```
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: Using the Ti.SDK 5.x, ATS keys are injected automatically by the build system. So I guess you may are using an older SDK that needed to inject it manually?

Comment: Thanks! I've reported this as a bug: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20597

Comment: @HansKnoechel I'm using latest SDK (5.2.0)